# Bivariate function that produces "ridge"-like surface

Tags: probability-distributions, 3d, mathematical-modeling

I'm trying to find the **right vocabulary** to describe a "ridge" like distribution that depends on two variables and how similar they are to each other. I'm imagining it looks something like the following. The utility of such a "ridge" like function is motivated by physical modeling. If $x$ is some expected distance and $y$ is the observed distance, then the probability $z$ surface should peak when $x - y = 0$ .

I admit this sounds really silly to ask, but I'm not finding relevant answers by searching for "ridge" functions. Would someone be able to point me in the right direction?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would a sufficiently rotated/scaled [Two-dimensional Gaussian function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_function#Two-dimensional_Gaussian_function) work?  Below, I've plotted $$f(x,y) = \exp\left(- \left(a(x - x_o)^2 + 2b(x-x_o)(y-y_o) + c(y-y_o)^2 \right)\right)$$ where

\begin{align}
a & = \frac{\cos^2\theta}{2\sigma_X^2} + \frac{\sin^2\theta}{2\sigma_Y^2} \\[4pt]
b & = -\frac{\sin2\theta}{4\sigma_X^2} + \frac{\sin2\theta}{4\sigma_Y^2} \\[4pt]
c & = \frac{\sin^2\theta}{2\sigma_X^2} + \frac{\cos^2\theta}{2\sigma_Y^2}.
\end{align}
Here $\theta$ is the angle of clockwise rotation.

[image]
See [CalcPlot3D](https://www.monroecc.edu/faculty/paulseeburger/calcnsf/CalcPlot3D/?type=z;z=exp(-(1/2)(((cos(t)/a)%5E2+(sin(t)/b)%5E2)x%5E2+(-sin(2*t)/a%5E2+sin(2*t)/b%5E2)xy+((cos(t)/b)%5E2+(sin(t)/a)%5E2)y%5E2));visible=true;umin=-5;umax=5;vmin=-5;vmax=5;grid=30;format=normal;alpha=-1;constcol=rgb(255,0,0);view=0;contourcolor=red;fixdomain=false&type=slider;slider=t;value=0.7853975;steps=100;pmin=-2;pmax=2;repeat=true;bounce=true;waittime=1;careful=false;noanimate=false;name=-1&type=slider;slider=a;value=2;steps=100;pmin=-2;pmax=2;repeat=true;bounce=true;waittime=1;careful=false;noanimate=false;name=-1&type=slider;slider=b;value=1;steps=100;pmin=-2;pmax=2;repeat=true;bounce=true;waittime=1;careful=false;noanimate=false;name=-1&type=window;hsrmode=3;nomidpts=true;anaglyph=-1;center=-6.021743100045566,12.938427845716461,10.414267324804355,1;focus=0,0,0,1;up=0.31492374305611076,-0.501852743862459,0.805584793511676,1;transparent=false;alpha=140;twoviews=false;unlinkviews=false;axisextension=0.7;xaxislabel=x;yaxislabel=y;zaxislabel=z;edgeson=true;faceson=true;showbox=true;showaxes=true;showticks=true;perspective=true;centerxpercent=0.5;centerypercent=0.5;rotationsteps=30;autospin=true;xygrid=false;yzgrid=false;xzgrid=false;gridsonbox=true;gridplanes=false;gridcolor=rgb(128,128,128);xmin=-5;xmax=5;ymin=-5;ymax=5;zmin=0;zmax=2;xscale=1;yscale=1;zscale=1;zcmin=-4;zcmax=4;zoom=0.333333;xscalefactor=1;yscalefactor=1;zscalefactor=3) for the full example, here I've used the variables $a = \sigma_{x} = 2$ and $b = \sigma_{y} = 1$ centered at the origin and rotated an angle of $t = \theta = \frac{\pi}{4}$.

Comment: Thanks, this is very simple and easy to model.